# x86/amd64 architecture Malware on ARM architecture malware Detonation

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, arm, cpu-architecture, x86

Situation: Thinking of making a malware detonator using an ARM single board computer, which has a file scanner in it.

Problem: I am scanning computers (x86 and/or amd64), therefore malwares will be written for those specific architectures. Trying to observe malware activity using an ARM architecture is essentially watching paint dry.

Question: Is there a way I can simulate an x86/amd64 environment on ARM?

Additional information: I looked at QEMU VMs as a method to do so, but I am open to containers that are able to simulate such conditions if possible.

Comment: What is a malware detonator supposed to be? How is this system supposed to work?

Comment: When a malware is found, it copies over (a bit counter intuitive), and monitors the malware behaviour and logs it.

Comment: So... analyser, maybe honeypot. "detonator" is not standard terminology, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Oh. So would a honeypot be able to simulate an x86/x64 platform?

Comment: @TimothyWong For that particular bit, you're looking for *emulation* (whcih, as you've noticed, qemu can do). But software emulation, especially of different instruction sets, tends to be *incredibly* slow. The Snapdragon 835 includes some hardware-assisted virt, but even that is probably rather slow. You're better off using a proper x86 chip - there are some fairly slim ones available, e.g. Intel NUCs.

Comment: @Bob I see where you're coming from. However my hardware can only consist of the ARM SBC. But I will look further into QEMU, and maybe do some research on honeypots.